# Issues including JSP file

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, tomcat

Trying to learn JSP pages now and for some reason I can't get my code to execute.  I'm trying to just call a function on the JSP page to update within a div. I have this running in Tomcat 8.

There are two files- One index.html and one test.jsp in the same directory.  Below is the code for each file:

Index.html:

```html
<%@ include file="test.jsp" %>
<html>
<body>
<div id="mainContainer"></div>
<script language="javascript">
    updatePage("Test JSP test works!");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.jsp:

```html
<%!
updatePage(text) {
    var container = this.getElementById('mainContainer');

    container.html = "<h1>" + text + "</h1>";
}
%>
```

The div isn't getting updated and I just have a blank page.  Why is my page not updating with the updated text? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK HTML cannot include JSP. This works for JSP including JSP.

Comment: You are trying to include a JSP-page, which is actually containing JavaScript instead of Java, by a server side include into an HTML . What a mess ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<%@ include... %>` is a JSP directive and it can only be used inside a JSP page, not in a plain HTML page. You should rename index.html to index.jsp if you want to do that.

Comment: Ok, I definitely understand why I was getting confused now. I thought HTML pages had to call JSP pages for some reason.  Been a while since I've done web development.  Thanks!